# How To Append Javascript Date To Multiple Inputs With Same ClassName?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append today's date to multiple inputs generated with a while statement. But each one of them returns blank. Any way to make this work? Thanks

PHP

```
//rest of code here
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
<input class="Paydate"  name="Paydate" value="" type="text">
}
```

JS

```
<script>
var mydate;
mydate = new Date();
document.getElementsByClassName('Paydate').value = mydate.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns live `HTMLCollection` rather than a single element, you need to iterate the collection

```
var dateStr =  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('Paydate') ).forEach( function(ele){
   ele.value = dateStr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for more info. You are treating it as if it returned a single HTML element.

What you'll need to do is iterate over the results returned and set the `value` property on each element returned not on the collection.

```js
var dateISOString =  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Paydate')).forEach(element => {
    element.value = dateISOString;
});
```

```html
<input class='Paydate' />
<input class='Paydate' />
<input class='Paydate' />
<input class='Paydate' />
```